# http POST request works in VSCode testing, but doesn't work with node-fetch in lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, openai-api, node-fetch

I have a lambda function that moderates input before calling the OpenAI API. It works perfectly in sam local, as well as directly in Visual Studio Code (not through my lambda URL). When I use my lambda function, I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": null,
    "param": null,
    "message": "'input' is a required property",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Here is the function that works locally (using SAM CLI invoke):

```
const moderationResponse = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/moderations', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `[PRIVATE]`
            },
            /* body is stringified before this step
               and looks like { input: inputText }
            */
            body: moderationBody
        })
```

I'm not really getting any worthwhile logs to try to fix anything.

Comment: `'input' is a required property`, let's print  out `stringified body`

Comment: It's a string, and it works locally with Sam cli and lambda gui test.

Comment: I can even try to pass it explicitly with postman and it still fails

Comment: `It's a string`, Could you provide the string?

Comment: Stringified version of `{input: 'This is sample input'}`

Comment: This is the string that you got from cloudwatch, right?

Comment: Yes. As I said - it passes in Sam cli testing, as well as the lambda gui test. It only fails through the actual http request, but the shape is exactly what it needs from the documentation.